# What does 这鸡儿啥东西 mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this as a comment on a video and I would like to know the meaning of this expression.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Any more context?

Comment: please repeat any Chinese text in body of question for ease of copying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the only *really* confusing part here is **鸡儿**, the other parts are quite self-explanatory:

- 这 = this
- 啥 = what
- 东西 = thing

**鸡儿** is a curse word from Southwest Mandarin.

Here's an entry from 《四川方言词典》

> 词语: 鸡儿
>
> 发音: ji1 er2
>
> 定义: (名) ①雏鸡。②<粗>男阴，骂人语，有的地方只有此义 ▷啊哟!你才香喃?比五香狗肉还香!只默到想巴结你么?哼，一条臭～! (山259)

It's essentially the same as 鸡巴 (cock) and is used almost in the exact same way.

Side-note: although the given pronunciation is ji1 er2 - you're more likely to hear it as a single syllable jier1 and even juer1 in some locales.

So 这鸡儿啥东西 basically means: *wtf is this thing?*

Comment: The most common way in Modern Mandarin to say this is "这是啥鸡儿东西", which means "wtf is this". This is rude in Mandarin. It might not be appropriate to be used in public comments.

Comment: The most common way in mandarin to say it is 这是啥鸡巴东西. 这是啥鸡儿东西 might be a dialect, which is not that common or familiar to the most of people I guess.